# What did Veronica spray on Hulk in Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-age-of-ultron

In Age of Ultron, after Wanda Maximoff sends Hulk into a rampage, Tony Stark has to call in Veronica to Pacify Hulk because Natasha is not available to pacify him.

Veronica sprays Hulk with a lot of liquid in the middle of the physical fight. The liquid weakens Hulk so that only a little more fighting is required before Hulk reverts into Bruce Banner.

**What is the fluid that Veronica sprays on Hulk?**

Comment: Old Spice... It reminds Hulk of this comercial he saw long time ago. That makes him sleepy.

Comment: Purely speculative but could it be Natasha's perfume and or pheromones? if she cant actually be there maybe it was thought that her smell (as smell is a massive memory trigger) could serve to calm the Hullk

Comment: I feel like this is going to be tricky to answer without a re-watch of the scene. Where's that remindme bot from reddit when you need it?

Comment: @CodeMed I meant to get more context, or there might be little visual cues that people can't remember. I just meant to say that you might have to wait for the release for a definitive answer

Comment: She sprayed mace and this is what all girls and Veronica from Archie do upon seeing eminent danger. And, I am not joking here. A high concentration mace should also work on Hulk.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### While the Hulk's exterior is quite robust and able to resist quite a bit of damage, early depictions of the Hulk showed him to be susceptible to gases, tranquilizers and being deprived of oxygen. For a time it was one of the only ways to subdue the Hulk long enough for the plot of stories to develop. The chemical agent depicted is never described in the cinematic release. Perhaps in the extended blue-ray it will get an official name.

[image]

- Eventually writers were no longer able to use any form of chemical against him and they even showed certain drugs like nerve agents which should kill normal humans, only temporarily weakening him or turning him into an even more dangerous version of the Hulk.

[image]

- It is most probable the spray used by the Hulk-suppression system Veronica used an agent designed to weaken the Hulk sufficiently that he could be rendered unconscious. And like most things where the Hulk is concerned, it took some time to work. Since Banner and Stark worked on the Veronica system together, they were likely confident the agent would work, at least for a time...

[image]

Comment: The problem with medicating the Hulk is if his body treats the agent as antagonistic, it will CAUSE the Hulk to emerge. Keeping him suppressed without causing him stress is the problem. Perhaps they will be able to do something like that one day...

Answer (score 4):

If I was to speculate, some sort of super tranquilliser that Banner helped develop. Everything onboard Veronica was something that Stark and Banner built just to stop the Hulk. Like the cage and of course the Hulkbuster armour.

Comment: It's amusing how they neglected to create a floor for the cage... enabling the Hulk to just dig underneath

Comment: They underestimate how smart the hulk can be.

Comment: @Petersaber: How would a floor for that cage work? Would the Hulk be so helpful as to move his feet as the floor attempted to slide into place? And how would the viewers even realize there was a floor to begin with?

Comment: @Ellesedil: Ehm, the cage could dig underneath his feet.

Comment: @Ellesedil if it was sudden enough, Hulk would probably raise his legs as some hard metallic objects hit them unexpectedly? It's an uncontrolled reaction to most living things.

Comment: Funny, I noticed the spray the first time. It was pretty obvious. And pretty self explanatory. Who doesn't know what sleeping gas does.

Answer (score 3):

Well in Winter Soldier, Nick Fury was using a certain chemical invented by Bruce Banner in order to lower his heart rate to the point of tricking medical professionals into thinking he is clinically dead.

Most likely it's the same chemical formula that Fury used, and Stark adopted it in order to pacify Hulk. There is no official explanation so far.